# Can't change color of contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have writen the code to find the contours and colorize them. however the video fails to save but it runs successfully.

I think I narrowed the issue to two lines of code, when I comment them, the video will save but it will be in grayscale which I don't want.

```
#change to black and white
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


gaus = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115,50)
frame = gaus






#Bluring the video
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(15,15),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
frame = blur

# Canny Edge
Canny = cv2.Canny(frame ,25,50)
frame = Canny


# Contours
contours,hierachy= cv2.findContours(frame,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

index = -1
thickness = 5


# these two lines bellow are preventing the file from being saved

img2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
frame = img2




cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (255,0,0), thickness)

# Save the video



cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

out.write(frame)
```

Comment: you can try drawing contours on original image. You have applied all the above operations to find contours. Now you have found the contours, draw it on original image instead of processed image.

Comment: cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) is not going to make the result the same as your colored frame. It will still be just gray, but 3 channels. Why are you doing that? You could just draw the contours on the original color frame or on the 1 channel grayscale image.

Comment: @fmw42 but when I run it, the video shows the color that I want. It just doesn't save it into the file

Comment: which video codec you are using.

Comment: @Karandeepdps .mov , but like I said the video saves in most cases only img2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
frame = img2                     seem to prevent the video from being saved, when I comment these two lines I am able to save the video